# Use Model Function In Laravel Query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How Can i resolve this problem
i want select users where it has enter the tournament and i use hasEnteredTournament Function in my User model too know that

this is User model:

```
public function scopeHasEnteredTournament($query){
    $active = Order::all()
        ->where('user_id','=',$this->id)
        ->where('status','=',1)
        ->where('pack_id','=',3)
        ->where('expired_at','>',now())
        ->first();
    $tournament = Tournament::all()
        ->where('status','=',1)
        ->where('start_at','<',now())
        ->where('end_at','>',now())
        ->first();
    if($active && $tournament){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and this is my controller codes:

```
$all = User::all()
        ->sortByDesc('tournamentPoints')
        ->where('hasEnteredTournament')
        ->take(200);
```

thanks very much

Comment: Try to avoid using `::all()` so much... Doing that takes every row from your database and puts it in memory as a `Collection` (PHP array wrapper in Laravel), then each additional function needs to modify that `Collection`. This is _incredibly_ inefficient. Compare to `User::orderBy('tournamentPoints', 'DESC')->where(...)->limit(200)->get();`. This is the same output, but uses your Database instead of PHP memory, and is _very_ efficient in comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you work with collection, you can use `filter` method :
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-filter

Answer (score -1):

just use this way...

```
$all = User::all()
        ->sortByDesc('tournamentPoints')
        ->hasEnteredTournament()
        ->take(200);
```

for more info see here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes